# Action Done in an entry dialog

Tags: android

I have a standard entry popup dialog

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

    builder.setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton(buttonPositif, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                   mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(EntryDialogFacade.this);
               }
           })
        .setNegativeButton(buttonNegatif, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // Send the negative button event back to the host activity
                   mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(EntryDialogFacade.this);
               }
           });        

    editText = new EditText(activity);
    editText.setLines(1);
    editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    builder.setView(editText);

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();        
    dialog.show();
```

I am trying to show the Done button on the entry field keyboard (see code snippet), however, this is not working this way.

Would have anyone experienced the same thing?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use `setSingleLine(true)` rather than `setLines(1)` and then you need an `EditorActionListener` to catch the `Done` key.

```
editText.setSingleLine(true);
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got IME Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank yo, but it seems to work perfectly without the listener.

Comment: Interesting that `android:singleLine="true"` in the xml is deprecated, but suggesting attribute: `android:maxLines="1"` does not work with `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`. I guess I will use deprecated one...